# How secure is Application State (ASP.NET) or Singleton (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: asp.net, security, web-applications, asp.net-core, cryptography

Is it secure to store some more sensitive web application data in Application State or Singleton? Are there any ways how attacker from outside could get to them (if yes, than how)? Thanks a lot.

Edit: I do not mean long time data storing like with DB. I am talking about store data comparable with cookie/session life cycle.

Comment: Singleton is not a type of storage...

Comment: If you look into MS Docs, there is service via Singleton used as an altenative to Application State in the ASP.NET Core. And I do not mean long type data storing (months+) like in the DB or file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe

I believe you are talking about the security perspective *(not about thread safe or persistent of data)*.

As they both are stored in server memory, it is not easy to hack the server's memory unless the web server itself is exploited.

So, I'll say it is pretty safe.

Comment: Thank you for the response.Yes, I mean security and  agreed with the premise about values inside server memory should not be accessible from outside. But is it usable for temporary storing such sensitive things like a generated encryption keys/salts/? Will be this kind of data safe there?

Comment: It is pretty safe. We store sensitive data in server's memory either one way or another, as it is not practical to access those data from `web.config` or `appsettings.json` for every request.